# How to find next key-value pair in Dictionary array using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary like

```
var secArray0 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Name", "gomesh" },
    { "EmpCode", "ID04" },
    { "DeptId", "1C" },
    { "Age", "25" }
};

var secArray1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Name", "Sunny" },
    { "EmpCode", "ID05" },
    { "DeptId", "1D" },
    { "Age", "28" }
};
```

..........
upto secArray3. Now i put all the above into another dictionary like

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] secArray =
{
    secArray0,
    secArray1,
    ...
};
```

Now in c# code, when i need to access any element by index like

```
secArray[0]["Name"].toString() --> i can get the name "gomesh" and so on.
```

Now my question is how do i iterate through `secArray` dictionary to find the next value/name i.e. "Sunny".
Please advise with some code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `foreach` on `Dictionary.Keys` or `Dictionary.Values`

Comment: " through `secArray` dictionary" - `secArray` is array, not a dictionary - please make sure to update post with info on what exactly you want to iterate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through you can just do a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < secArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(secArray[i]["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: ok fine but why does Console.WriteLine(secArray[i+1]["Name"].ToString()); throws up error where i=1 when at index 1 value exists???

Comment: Because on the last iteration you are referencing the next iteration which doesn't exist. The code I put in place is for i not i +1. You can do an if statement to only do a write line if you are not on the last iteration if you are doing i +1.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is how do i iterate through secArray dictionary

You could use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in secArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so it would be:

```
foreach (var kvp in secArray[0])
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

secArray is not a dictionary, it is an array of dictionaries. Therefore you just need to move the indexing to get the next element, like:

```
secArray[1]["Name"].ToString()
```

So, you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < secArray.Length; i++) 
{
    var something = secArray[i]["Name"].toString(); 
}
```